# Python - deleting programmatically created word and pdf files

Tags: python, pdf

I have a code that generates word documents from an excel file using mailmerge and later converts the word documents to PDF then from PDF to PNG. I am looking for a way to delete the word documents after creating the PDFs and deleting the PDFs after creating the PNG files.

Below is the code I am working with:

```
#Code for the conversion from docx to pdf    
 wdFormatPDF = 17
    
    basepath="C:/Users/.../images"
    
    os.chdir(base_path)
    with os.scandir(base_path) as entries:
        for entry in entries:
            if entry.is_file() and (entry.name[-4:]=="docx"):
                in_file=base_path+entry.name
                out_file=base_path+entry.name[:-4]+"pdf"
                word = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Word.Application')   
                doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
                doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
                doc.Close()
                print("Document "+out_file+" created !!!")
                #word.Quit()  
    word.Quit()
    
    #Code for the conversion from pdf to png 
    
    basepath="C:/Users/.../images"
    
    os.chdir(basepath)
    with os.scandir(basepath) as entries:
        for entry in entries:
            if entry.is_file():
                if entry.name[-3:]=="pdf":
                    input_filename=basepath + entry.name
                    images=convert_from_path(input_filename)
                    for i, image in enumerate(images):
                        fname=entry.name[:-4]+".PNG"
                        image.save(fname,"PNG") 
                        print("Document "+fname+" created !!!\n")
```

Comment: You can use `os.remove()` to delete any file. So, after you finished creating the documents, just loop through the source files and use this function to delete them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You should save your file links in a variable and then simply delete it after they are no longer needed:

```
import os
os.remove("/link/to/the/file.pdf")
```

Or if you are sure there are no other pdf/docx files in the directory:

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".pdf") or filename.endswith(".docx"): 
         os.remove(filename)
```